# PostgreSQL 9.2 - Conditional insert fails with duplicate key violation

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-insert, postgresql-9.2

The following conditional insert works only if the item already exists! (does not go on with attempting to insert).

If the item does not exist, I get duplicate key violation (duplicate key violates unique constraint)!
Using postgresql 9.2

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mytable_handle, title, description) 
select '1234/9876', 'Title here', 'description here' 
from mytable where not exists 
(select 1 from mytable where mytable_handle = '1234/9876')
```

(mytable_handle is the pkey)

Comment: Question: `mytable_handle` is a *character* columns? As a primary key?

Comment: Actually we are using strings for that field in the likes of '1234/9876'. Just updated the question on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select '1234', 'Title here', 'description here' 
from mytable where not exists 
(select 1 from mytable where mytable_handle = '1234');
```

will return the tuple `'1234', 'Title here', 'description here'` once for **each** row that already exists in the table, if the `mytable_handle` value does not exist. Run the `select` on its own and you will see for yourself

You want:

```
select '1234', 'Title here', 'description here' 
where not exists 
(select 1 from mytable where mytable_handle = '1234');
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b331f/1